# In Android on Orientation change activity with fragment is not picking up layout files correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an activity in fragment with three bottom navigation tabs. Each having two xml files for portrait and landscape. 
Whenever I change the orientation layout used to show appropriate xml files but was restarting activity.

So in manifest file I included

> android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

After this change, activity is not restarting but on orientation change layout is not picking appropriate xml files.
i.e when change from portrait to landscape view is showing portrait file not picking up landscape xml file.

Below is my code for inflating view from fragment.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_data_monitor, container, false);
  return view;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

```
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_data_monitor, container, false);
      initUI(); // Define all your xml attributes, like, EditText, Button etc
      return view;
    }
```

and use one more method, i.e. onConfigurationChanged();

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        initUI(); // Call this again.
    }
```

Hope this will help.